# why mysql_real_escape_string is changing my url

Tags: php

if data is

```
    $data = '<a href="http://www.abc.com">my Anchor</a>
```

this function

```
    $res = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($data) : $data;
    $res = mysql_real_escape_string($res); // php 4.3 and higher
```

Convert it to

```
    <a href="\"http://www.abc.com"">my Anchor</a>
```

why

Comment: Start to debug your code and find out which of the many code is changing the value in a way you dislike.

Comment: code is fine i debuged it problem is these two line i sapreatly try to run it too. its not working the way it should be

Comment: I would assume if something isn't working the way it should be, it by definition isn't fine?

Comment: Remove that line: `$res = mysql_real_escape_string($res); // php 4.3 and higher` - this solves your issue. You don't need a database escape function for `echo`, that's just some idiotic code copied from an unreliable source.

Answer (score 1):

The first line

```
$res = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($data) : $data;
```

checks whether magic_quotes_gpc is set. It checks with the [get_magic_quotes_gpc() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php). If the flag is set, it calls [stripslashes](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on the string. This function removes \ from the string. For example it turns every occurence of \' into ' and every occurence of \\ into \.

The second line

```
$res = mysql_real_escape_string($res);
```

further modifies the string. It replaces ' with \'. Usually [mysql_real_escape_string](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is used to avoid security issues, specifically [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your code is vulnerable when you send SQL queries to an SQL database and build the SQL statement manually with string concatenation.

All in all:

1. The first line changes the string to <a href="http://www.abc.com">my Anchor</a>. That's the same string.
2. The second line changes the string to <a href=\"http://www.abc.com\">my Anchor</a>. This is the same string, where " was replaced by \".

These commands only make sense when you use string concatenation to build SQL statements.